# Wordpress/Woocommerce search on the same page

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, admin

I'm building a woocommerce plugin and i would like to have a search box for sku on one page in the admin section (so far no issue) but i would like the result to be displayed on the same page. e.g a ajax search and not a php search. Anyone has a tip for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below plugin for the same:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-in-place/